# Как пишутся имена Элла, Алла, Римма, Стелла, Белла, Анна, Инна с уменьшительно-ласкательным суффиксом?

Tags: орфография, суффиксы, удвоенные-согласные

Как пишутся женские имена с удвоенным согласным с суффиксами

*-ул-, -ус- юл, -юс-, -ун-, -юн-*?

Нет жесткого правила?

А то я здешнюю Риммулю то так, то эдак пишу...

Алла - Аллюсик? Аллюня? О_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот информация с [**Грамоты**](https://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5).

**Вопрос № 280262**
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать Аллочка или Алочка? И почему?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Правильно: *Аллочка*. Одна согласная буква вместо двойной согласной пишется только в уменьшительных и фамильярных формах личных имен с суффиксом *-к(а)*, например: *Алла – Алка, Жанна – Жанка, Элла – Элка, Кирилл – Кирилка*  и т. д. В ласкательных формах имен на *-очка, -ушка* **двойные согласные** сохраняются: *Аллочка, Эллочка, Жанночка, Аннушка, Кириллушка.*

**Вопрос № 256291**
...Элла — Эллочка, Жанна — Жанночка, но: Анна — Анечка, Анка, Жанка.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Что касается уменьшительной формы *Анечка*, то она образована не от *Анна*, а от *Аня*, поэтому двойной согласной здесь взяться просто неоткуда.

Алла — Ала, Алюня, Алюся, Аля.
Анна — Ана, Аннета, Аннечка, Анночка, Аннуся, Аннуша, Аннушка, Аннюня, Аннюся, Ануся, Ануша, Анюра, Анюся, Анюта, Анюша, Аня, Нуся, Нюта, Нюша (Нюрца, Нюшинца, Нюшенция).
Римма — Рима, Риммура, Риммушка, Рина, Римуля, Мура.
Рим — Римуся (так в словаре).

Остальное можно посмотреть здесь:
[Указатель производных (уменьшительных) имен](http://gramota.ru/slovari/info/petr/imsm/)

Comment: Спасибо! Вот как так: и Римуля и Риммуля, а? ***Римма  латинское женское имя (устарелое мужское). Происходит от названия города Рима. Производные: Риммушка, Риммуля, Риммусик, Риммулька, Риммура, Мура, Рима, Римуля, Рина. Римма христианский святой II века, почитаемый в лике мучеников.…*** https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/personal_names/19131/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F

Answer (score 2):

Общего правила, видимо, нет, но есть практика. Все эти имена, кроме Анны, употребляются с суффиксом **-очк-**, причём для Беллы существует вариант написания с одним **-л-**. Для Анны характерны варианты "Аннушка" и "Анюта". Всё это относительно нейтрально звучит. Прочие варианты излишне фамильярны, включая стилизацию под мужской род (Бельчонок, Иннусик, Элланчик и др.). При близком общении такие придумки возможны, и ограничений здесь нет (можно хоть Элладушкой или Антанточкой барышню называть, если позволяет).