# Почему Википедия не склоняет капеллу Карафы?

Tags: орфография, склонение-имён-собственных

> [Карафа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0) (итал. Carafa, Caraffa) — знатный неаполитанский род, к
>   которому принадлежали папа Павел IV и ещё 14 кардиналов, включая
>   нескольких его племянников.
>
> Семейство Карафа происходило из Неаполя. В XIII—XIV вв. оно достигло
>   положения одного из влиятельнейших феодальных родов Неаполитанского
>   королевства. Диомед Карафа снискал известность как писатель. В 1467
>   году Оливьеро Карафа стал первым из 15 кардиналов, вышедших из этого
>   семейства. Благодаря этому род Карафа сумел закрепиться в Риме, а
>   также постепенно добиться влияния и в других областях Италии. Этому
>   также способствовало родство Карафа с Фомой Аквинским, что получило
>   отображение **на фреске работы Филиппино Липпи в капелле Карафа** в
>   римской церкви Санта-Мария-сопра-Минерва (где был похоронен О.Карафа).

У меня:

> И вот где-то за колонной стукнуло евро, сработала машинка — и капеллу
>   Карафы, посвящённую апофеозу Фомы Аквинского, залило светом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, действительно, в абсолютном большинстве случаев и *Капелла Карафа*,  и сама фамилия в Википедии не склоняются.
Если следовать [правилам склонений фамилий](http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_8_familii/), то фамилия *Карафа* должна склоняться. Нашлись этому и некоторые подтверждения.

Самая примечательная в храме — капелла [Карафы](http://www.russian-globe.com/N165/Mesh.Rome8.htm) (справа от алтаря), названная в честь папы-инквизитора Папы IV Карафы, автора "Индекса запрещенных книг".

Джойс ДиДонато выступит в сопровождении оркестра Лионской оперы и представит долгожданное исполнение множества известных арий, сочиненных неаполитанцами, в том числе Беллини, [Карафой](https://www.classictic.com/ru/%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE__%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2/27651/?sorting=date_asc), Меркаданте, Пачини и Россини.

КАРАФА — [итал. Carafa] Антонио (25.03.1538, Неаполь — 13.01.1591, Рим), маркиз ди Монтенеро, кард., издатель Вульгаты. 3-й сын неаполитанского патриция Ринальдо **Карафы (Карафелло)**.
[Православная Энциклопедия](http://www.pravenc.ru/text/1680999.html)

Может быть, на такое "упорное несклонение" влияет вот эта особая часть — "Карафелло" (которая по правилам НЕ склоняется)?

Comment: Римуль, есть! Приходите сюда: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444619/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB )))

Answer (score 1):

Сама фамилия по существующим правилам (итальянские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на -а безударный) *должна* склоняться; пример: http://www.pravenc.ru/text/1680999.html. Однако "**Капелла Карафа**" (*La Capella Carafa*) в оригинале грамматически не является "Капеллой Караф**ы**" (иначе было бы предложное сочетание *La Capella **di** Carafa*, которое соответствует притяжательности и нашему родительному падежу) - это просто *название* капеллы. Вероятно, русское название (см. подпись под иллюстрацией: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0) учитывает эту особенность оригинала. Возможна и иная трактовка "несклонения": отнесение не к конкретному представителю рода, а ко всей фамилии (капелла семьи/рода Карафа).

Comment: Саш, спасибо. Вот эту тонкость *La Capella Carafa - La Capella di Carafa* я автору отправлю.